# What is the recommended way to dispose of a used water filter?

Tags: recycling, waste, water

I have just replaced water filters for the water filtration system recently. There are a total 5 filters. 1 of them is ceramic, the other 4 are made of other materials which could probably be opened to be able to dispose of the plastic body separately.

For the ceramic filter, is there any way of dismantling it? It is made of 2 parts, the bottom stand for mounting and the ceramic body. I think inside the ceramic body is the activated carbon block.

Just want to make sure if there is currently no alternative before dumping it.

#### Edit 2021/5/25

I have tried to make an enquiry to the manufacturer.

> Thank you for your e-mail, the filters can generally only go into
> landfill.
>
> However if you do remove the black mount from the end you can use the
> rest in your Garden for drainage.

I am not sure if it is a good answer so I am not going to put it in answer field yet.

Because my filter system is a multi-filtering system.
The ceramic filter come first and then the other 4 filters with different purposes such as adding hydrogen, with another activated carbon inside and so on. The first entrance ceramic has done a great job in filtering all the heavy metal already so I don't think it is appropriate to use the activated carbon inside in my case. Because it probably consists of many filtered heavy metal ion. If it goes to the soil, and I plant eatable plants then it will either poison the plant and I will probably eat the heavy metal ion myself if it is polluted. (although I am not a chemist but a programmer LOL, not sure if it is 100% right or not :) )

Answer (score 2):

Whirlpool used to have a program for recycling but it was discontinued due to lack of participation.

There is a water filter recycling service available here: https://www.recyclewaterfilters.com/fee-to-recycle-water-filters.html
for a fee.

The activated carbon could be removed and used in the garden if it was towards the end of the filtration system (heavy metals would be in the ceramic section), you could then recycle the plastic cases and deposit the ceramic in the trash. At least all the portions that can be recycled will be.

Comment: do you have the information about the heavy metal and ceramic? it would be a good information providing in the answer.